# What should be the sequence of Morning Routine?

Tags: yoga, practice, meditation, health

I am confused about morning routine. After waking up, In what order should one perform these actions:

- Brushing Teeth (Is usually the first thing)
- Bathing (15 mins)
- Meditation (takes 15-30 mins, Preferable in brahma muhurta)
- Exercise (takes 40 mins to 1 hour)
- Worship (15 mins)

The only confusing thing about it that after exercise I am sweating and I don't feel like doing meditation or worship in that state. But if I exercise before bathing then I loose brahma muhurta time for meditation.

Is there any mention in our Sanatans(Hindu) text for this scenario?

Comment: There is no concept of devoting time for physical exercises in our scriptures. The morning routine as per the Smritis goes like goes like - Waking up -> Defecation -> Brushing teeth -> Bath -> Sandhyavandana -> Worship.

Comment: After waking up one should make the schedule for the day

Comment: @অনু, Don't we have Yoga for physical well-being? Wouldn't exercise come under same category? I thought Yoga was part of our scripts, is it not?

Comment: Sir is this like a Qn on which you wish to seek advice from the fellow stack members or you explicitly want shastras/acharyas opinion on this?

Comment: I wanted to know what does our Sanatans(Hindu) text says. I was surprised by your response that Yoga was not included in our shastras.